# Why can't I make trivial edits on my posts for extra reputation?

Tags: discussion

How I make trivial edits for extra reputation:

1. I make a minor edit on my question or answer.
2. The post gets pushed onto the "activity" tab of the front page.
3. It receives attention to other users; they upvote my post and I gain extra reputation.

### But why cannot I do such?

The mods say it is "disruptive" - why is it disruptive?  And... I pretty much get it isn't really recommended, but WHY?

Dom-sama says on this question: [Are "Londonderry Air", "Danny Boy", and "You Raise Me Up" the same song?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/9975/are-londonderry-air-danny-boy-and-you-raise-me-up-the-same-song)

> Maika, you cannot just use edits to bump your post nor use the edit reasons for meta comments that don't relate to anything on the site. You've done this on several SEs and it's not OK and an abuse of the system. This post is now locked due to this and this will not be tolerated in the future.

And then he/she says when I brought it on the [meta:](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/565/post-lock-are-londonderry-air-danny-boy-and-you-raise-me-up-the-same-so?noredirect=1#comment1220_565)

> Please read the comment on that question as it explains why this happened. If you still don't understand it please at least reference what about it you don't understand in this post. You've asked several questions on meta that have already been answered by comments so please from now on look at the comments first and if you don't think they answer your question please explain why.
>
> And to make it extreamly clear why it was locked and this is not acceptable, the edit reason "Only an act of true love can save me" is not acceptable. That's not the point of edits nor is just editing them to bump which you have a history on music SE, this SE, and [other SEs.](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4198/how-to-deal-with-tiny-edits-intending-to-raise-a-questions-visibility-for-the-p) The combination of the edit reason, the lack of content in the edit, and your history make it hard to see this as anything but edit abuse. It was also flagged as such by other users.
>
> If your question is why can't use edits to just bump your post is it's not the point of the edits and you've been told this on multiple sites including music SE and politics SE as linked above. Edits are to clarify/improve your post a side effect of that is being bumped so the community can make sure nothing was defaced or get a chance to adjust voting after clarifying edits. You are trying to use a system for your benefit, not for it's intended use as we asked you not to do many times.
>
> If you are asking about the why the edit reason was inappropriate, it has nothing to do with the edit so is abuse of the feature as well. You can't just use edit messages to try and progress meta actions it's entirely inappropriate.

Well... is this similar to sockpuppetry?  I **do** actually have a blatant history of sockpuppetry on Music SE, including sockpuppet upvoting and anonymous abuse-editing, but not on this SE nor in "other sites."  This is what happened on Music SE (From mods' point of view):

1. On 1/6/19, an account coming from my IP named "Kaho Hinata" was found to be serially upvoting me.  The account was realized as a sockpuppet of mine; I was suspended for 7 days for this.

> [image]

2. On 4/24/19, an anonymous user was found to be constantly making trivial edits on my posts.  The edits were coming from my IP.  I was attempting to hide actions (since I was already asked to stop).  I ended up getting suspended for 30 days - this was similar to the sockpuppet upvoting I've done which resulted in the previous suspension.

> [image]

3. On 8/16/19, two more suspicious anonymous edits were coming out from my IP.  I ended up with a 365-day suspension immediately.  This, as my third suspendable offense, was a follow-up from my second suspension for anonymous editing, which was also a follow-up from my first suspension for sockpuppet upvoting.

> [image]

But I never sockpuppeted on this SE, nor on any other sites other than Music SE.  **Why is this not allowed?**

Comment: Please stop sharing doctored mod messages.  You were suspended for 180 days  on music SE and then you did more anonymous edits that cause it to be extended to a year from the point with a different mod message. So the 3rd mod message posted is altered because the message for the 356 day suspension was very different.

Comment: Well... yes... you were right... but I have merged those together into one whole ban (it pretty much already was) to match the regular 7/30/365.  Well... the offenses listed on 1 and 2 were completely correct, right?

Comment: @Dom edited.  Better?

Comment: Not really because that entire section felt irrelevant.  Your suspensions here had nothing directly to do with your suspension there.

Comment: You have an apology to the network in your profile, yet you keep trying to find ways to break the system. Can you please stop breaking stuff and just use the site the way it's intended? If you have trouble with understanding how the site works, we can help with that. Just, stop trying to break things on purpose.

Comment: @Mast - yes.  Fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it's abuse. We've said this a lot. The point of edits is to improve your post, not get more rep from them. Using them for other purposes besides improving your post is considered abuse.

You also cannot just put whatever you want into the edit message as it's supposed to be about *why* you are editing, not meta commentary like "Only an act of true love can save me" or "Please do not ask multiple questions at once NOR write a random title that is not relevant to the topic of the question. This is taken VERY SERIOUSLY on SE, and it can result in your question being closed and/or deleted.". Both are not appropriate because they aren't the reason why you edited.

---

The two points above have been stated many times so I want to reiterate, please just listen to the community and the mods.

Comment: But the two quotes listed here are only minor issues on this site.  So I don't think it makes sense for you to say that I've done this on "Music SE, this SE, and in other SEs."  Could you clarify this?

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya No. You know what you've done. Just listen to the advice offered here.

Comment: I promise from now on that I will figure out a different way to do so.  I will not make a useless edit on my post just for extra votes/badges.

Comment: Dom, what will happen if I just ignore and end up using a sock to do this like what had happened on the other site?